# Excel Vba .find

Tags: vba, excel

Hi the names Mark and I am a new to VBA.

I have two workbooks that contain data that needs to be compared. I am currently using this code to do the comparisons. It works and gives the results I require.

What I am looking to add is the ability to search within a description in my second workbook range **D:D** and bring back matches to the cell **Cells(rw, 4**) in my active work book. This information would be placed in **Cells(rw, 29**)

I have researched the **find** function but can not get it to work across two workbooks. The challenge here being that the work book I search from or active workbooks name changes.

```
Sub VlookUpExampleDifferBooks()

'This example look up table in different book and sheet (TABLE 1 - ActiveSheet, TABLE 2 - CMF.xlxs and sheet1)
'Validate_Down Macro

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rw As Long
Dim mx As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Find Last Row
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

For rw = 11 To LastRow ' Loop until rw = Lastrow
Cells(rw, 27) = "'" & Cells(rw, 4)
Cells(rw, 28) = "'" & Cells(rw, 2)
Cells(rw, 25) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 27), Workbooks("CMF Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:D"), 3, False) ' Vlookup function
Cells(rw, 26) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 28), Workbooks("CMF Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:D"), 2, False) ' Vlookup function
Cells(rw, 20) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 18), Workbooks("CMF Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("C:D"), 2, False) ' Vlookup function
Cells(rw, 19) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 18), Workbooks("CMF Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("C:E"), 3, False) ' Vlookup function

If IsError(Cells(rw, 25)) Then Cells(rw, 25) = ""
If IsError(Cells(rw, 26)) Then Cells(rw, 26) = ""
If Cells(rw, 25) <> Cells(rw, 26) Then Cells(rw, 18) = Cells(rw, 25) & "/" & Cells(rw, 26)
If Cells(rw, 25) = Cells(rw, 26) Then Cells(rw, 18) = "'" & Cells(rw, 25)
If Cells(rw, 25) <> Cells(rw, 26) And Cells(rw, 26) = "" Then Cells(rw, 18) = "'" & Cells(rw, 25)
If Cells(rw, 25) <> Cells(rw, 26) And Cells(rw, 25) = "" Then Cells(rw, 18) = "'" & Cells(rw, 26)
If IsError(Cells(rw, 20)) Then Cells(rw, 20) = ""
If IsError(Cells(rw, 19)) Then Cells(rw, 19) = ""

Next
```

Comment: **First.** Have you tried to record macro to catch the way `.find method` is working across workbooks? I can confirm, it's possible and quite easy. **Second.** For workbooks changing names- you need to give an idea how you want to solve it- there are lots of possible solutions depending on the goal. We are not able to suggest them all. **Third.** This line in your code: `Activesheet.Select` doesn't have any sense therefore please delete it.

Comment: @KazJAw - Thanks for the prompt response. With regards to the file names, I receive files from my suppliers which I name according to the supplier. The format and structure of the file remains unaltered. I have not tried to use the macro recording. Not sure how I would use it. Sorry still finding my feet with coding.

Comment: I would suggest using [`FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862446%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Search here in SO for how to use it (which is not difficult). Additionally, you will need `object variables` which make it easy to operate with two workbooks at a time.

Comment: All the files contain Price List. eg ABE_Price List_20130122

Comment: here's a link that will help you understand more about `.Find` method. Also, the author created a function that finds all the matches and returns all matches. [LINK to FINDING FIND](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx). It is a good read actually. hope this helps. Also, on top of what KazJaw suggested using the `FileDialog` , you can also use [`Application.GetOpenFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834966.aspx) method.

Comment: @ KazJaw Thanks for the info, I have recorded a macro and am busy working through the code.

Comment: @ L42 Thanks for the info and link. Has helped tremendously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are having trouble using the `FIND` function because it is designed to find values/strings within a single cell.  You are attempting to search through an entire column.  A brute force way to solve your problem is to loop through your raw data column & check each cell for the desired match.  I've included an example in your code below.

I used the `instr()` function rather than `find`.  They work much the same, but `instr()` is a bit more convenient for use in VBA.

```
Sub VlookUpExampleDifferBooks()

'This example look up table in different book and sheet (TABLE 1 - ActiveSheet, TABLE 2 - CMF.xlxs and sheet1)
'Validate_Down Macro

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rw As Long
Dim mx As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Find Last Row
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

For rw = 11 To LastRow ' Loop until rw = Lastrow
Cells(rw, 27) = "'" & Cells(rw, 4)
Cells(rw, 28) = "'" & Cells(rw, 2)
Cells(rw, 25) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 27), Workbooks("CMF Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:D"), 3, False) ' Vlookup function
Cells(rw, 26) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 28), Workbooks("CMF Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:D"), 2, False) ' Vlookup function
Cells(rw, 20) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 18), Workbooks("CMF Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("C:D"), 2, False) ' Vlookup function
Cells(rw, 19) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 18), Workbooks("CMF Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("C:E"), 3, False) ' Vlookup function


'Loop through all cells in column D and check each one for the value in cells(rw,4)
For Each testcell In Workbooks("CMF Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
       If InStr(1, testcell.Value, Cells(rw, 4).Value, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then 
            Cells(rw, 29).Value = Cells(rw, 4).Value
            Exit For

        End If
Next testcell

If IsError(Cells(rw, 25)) Then Cells(rw, 25) = ""
If IsError(Cells(rw, 26)) Then Cells(rw, 26) = ""
If Cells(rw, 25) <> Cells(rw, 26) Then Cells(rw, 18) = Cells(rw, 25) & "/" & Cells(rw, 26)
If Cells(rw, 25) = Cells(rw, 26) Then Cells(rw, 18) = "'" & Cells(rw, 25)
If Cells(rw, 25) <> Cells(rw, 26) And Cells(rw, 26) = "" Then Cells(rw, 18) = "'" & Cells(rw, 25)
If Cells(rw, 25) <> Cells(rw, 26) And Cells(rw, 25) = "" Then Cells(rw, 18) = "'" & Cells(rw, 26)
If IsError(Cells(rw, 20)) Then Cells(rw, 20) = ""
If IsError(Cells(rw, 19)) Then Cells(rw, 19) = ""

Next
```

Hope this helps!

-Jacob