# How to search for specific word or words in a column of data and return that value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like my macro to search a column of data for specific words. If these words appear in the data, I would like to return these values to another cell. If not I would like it to return "None". Below are the results I would expect.

Search column of data for word "Restricted" and "Unrestricted". If only one of these words appear in the data, return that word as a value (Ex. If only "Restricted" is in the data, return "Restricted". If both words appear in the data, return "Restricted/Unrestricted"). If neither of the words appear in the data, return "None".

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. SO is not actually meant to be a code writing service. Have you tried anything so far and where are you stuck? Please see [ask], thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Vba .find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318301/excel-vba-find)

Comment: @BigBen apologies if this was the wrong forum as I am new to SO. I have built 90% of my Macro but am stuck at this one task and haven't been able to find anything online. I thought about using case select but I believe that only works when looking at a single cell and not a column of data. Also, I don't think that function allows you to search for multiple values.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question with the code you have so far.

Comment: No need of VBA here. Use the `countif` function. To count the `Restricted` and `Unresticted` in a column. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

No need of VBA here. Use the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34). To count the `Restricted` and `Unresticted` in a column.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,"Restricted")>0,COUNTIF(A:A,"Unrestricted")>0),"Restricted/Unrestricted",IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"Restricted")>0,"Restricted",IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"Unrestricted")>0,"Unrestricted","None")))
```

This formula checks column A.

Answer (score 0):

You have pay attention to the fact that the word Unrestricted contains the word Restricted as well if you compare them case-insensitive.

You can use Instr function with vbBinaryCompare (case-sensitive) as its last argument to see if a string appears in another string.

```
StrText = cell.Value

If InStr(1, StrText, "Unrestricted", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, StrText, "Restricted", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    StrResult = "Restricted/Unrestricted"
ElseIf InStr(1, StrText, "Unrestricted", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, StrText, "Restricted", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
    StrResult = "Unrestricted"
ElseIf InStr(1, StrText, "Unrestricted", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 And InStr(1, StrText, "Restricted", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    StrResult = "Restricted"
Else
    StrResult = "None"
End Sub
```

Comment: A recommendation: If your last `ElseIf` is the correct result you run `InStr` 6 times. But you only need to run it 2 times if you put the result in a variable like `ResultUnrestricted = InStr(1, StrText, "Unrestricted", vbBinaryCompare)` and then use the variable to compare. That saves you time because you don't do the same comparison over and over.